# Java PKCS#11 configuration - 'slot' and 'slotListIndex'

Tags: java, cryptography, pkcs#11

What's the difference between these parameters? I've read [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) but I still doubt. Is it just the indexing rule (1..N vs 0..N-1) or anything else? I'd like to see a better explanation of these parameters if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is my first experience learning about PKCS#11. This answer comes from reading docs for a few of the [PKCS#11 wrappers listed on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS11).

Correlating those docs with the Java API, I think `slot` (aka "Slot Id") is a slot identifier returned for a given slot within the list of slots returned by `C_GetSlotList`. `slotListIndex` appears to be the index into that list.

Mentally, I'm visualizing that `C_GetSlotList` would return a list such as:

```
Index    Id     Name
0        Foo    "Super Secure HSM"
1        Bar    "Awesome Card Reader"
```

In this case the "Awesome Card Reader" could be identified via `slot = "Bar"` or via `slotListIndex = 1`.

I think the confusing element here is that the API uses an integer for the Identifier, which is why it's hard to understand why it would be different from simply indexing into the list of slots.

In the end, it seems you'll need to get the slot list no matter what, so I don't think it matters which value you choose to identify the slot you're interested in.